# Can I perform conditional DynamoDB calls in a single call?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Lets say I have a table that stores user data. It stores 2 types of data - a UserId (partition key) with attributes (json blob). The other type is a reference to the UserId, based off of values within the attributes, for example, here would be 3 rows of the table:

```
pk                           attributes                                                  userId
5                         | { email: example@example.com, tel: 123456789 }             | null
email/example@example.com | null                                                       |   5
phone/123456789           | null                                                       |   5
```

This is so I am able to query directly off of values to obtain attributes, without needing to do a scan and filter (a very compute intensive operation on large tables).

My question is: Can I, in a single query, do something like getByPartitionKey(email/example@example.com), obtain the userId, and then use that userID to query for the whole attributes document, without doing 2 individual requests? Something akin to a join in SQL.

Comment: If you want arbitrary column searches, then you should choose a search engine, such as Elasticsearch/OpenSearch, rather than a NoSQL database. Or use the two in combination.

Answer (score 2):

Your data model is very wrong, here is how to achieve what you want:

| pk | sk | phone | email | other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user123 | user123 | 0293480983 | example@example.com | some map {} |

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE PK = 'user123'`

This would allow you to get all of the information for a given userId. If you want the same information but this time by email, you create a [GSI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) on the email attribute:

| email | pk | sk | phone | other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| example@example.com | user123 | user123 | 0293480983 | some map {} |

`SELECT * FROM mytable.myindex WHERE email = 'example@example.com'`

Comment: Would this not require a GSI for every single thing I want to query on? Additional GSIs incur heavier costs and in this instance, I would require 10+ GSIs (there's more attributes than I've listed, this just gets across the general idea). Furthermore, if there was to be a schema change, and lets say I stored more than 20 GSIs (the limit), where would that leave me?

Also, your point is a valid analysis, however does not answer my original question.

Comment: I didn't answer your original question as I don't want you to get trapped by a bad schema. You're correct, if you wanted to query 20 different ways you'd need 19 GSIs. DynamoDB is key-value store, if you want query flexibility then you should integrate with OpenSearch.